# unix で、 特定のディレクトリで、 shebang が /bin/sh のものだけ実行権限を付与したい

Tags: unix

諸事情により、特定のディレクトリの中の、実行権限がすべて吹っ飛んでしまいました; すべて 664 のパーミッションになっています。

このディレクトリには、実行可能(だったはずの)シェルスクリプトと、 windows 用の .bat ファイルが混合しています。

この状態で、実行可能だったはずのシェルスクリプトすべてに実行権限を付与したいと考えています。具体的には、実行可能だったシェルスクリプトは、すべて shebang が #!/bin/sh だったので、これらに対して chmod を実行したいのですが、これを、なるべく簡単に実現する方法はありますか？

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`file`コマンドでファイルの種類を調べられます。手元の環境ですと

```
$ file -bi bin/some.sh
text/x-shellscript; charset=us-ascii
```

という出力を得られますので、この文字列が含まれるか`grep`で判定できます。

```
$ file -bi bin/some.sh | grep -q 'text/x-shellscript' && echo "shell script!"
shell script!
```

あとはこれをループしてやればいいでしょう。

```
$ for f in somedir/*; do file -bi "$f" | grep -q 'text/x-shellscript' && echo chmod +x "$f"; done
chmod +x bin/some.sh
...
```

問題なさそうなら`echo`を消せば`chmod`が実行されます。

Answer (score 3):

以下は find と GNU grep を使う方法です。

```bash
$ find [target_dir] -type f -exec grep -PlZs '\A#!/bin/sh' {} \+ | xargs -0 chmod +x
```

GNU grep の `-P` オプション(Perl 互換の正規表現が使用可能)における `\A` はファイルの先頭にマッチする正規表現です。また、この場合は `[target_dir]` 以降の全ての通常ファイルが対象になりますので、`[target_dir]` 内のファイルだけを対象にしたい場合は find に `-maxdepth 1` を付ける必要があるかもしれません。

※ Linux distribution では GNU grep がデフォルトかと思いますが、UNIX 系 OS ではオプショナルでしょうから、`unix` カテゴリからは外れている回答かもしれません

Comment: `#!`と`/bin/sh`の間に空白が含まれる可能性も考慮した方がいいかと。またGNU grepを仮定するのであれば`-r`オプションを使えば`find`も必要なくなるかと。

Answer (score 2):

どこにでもある sed と test を使うとこう書けます。

```
for f in your_dir/*; do s=`sed '-e /^#!\\/bin\\/sh$/!x' -eq "$f"` && if [ "$s" ]; then chmod +x "$f"; fi; done
```

sed のコマンドですが、エスケープシーケンスを解除すると `-e /^#!\/bin\/sh$/!x`, `-eq` になります。
一つ目で正規表現 `/^#!\/bin\/sh$/` により shebang にマッチさせ、マッチしなければホールドスペース(初期状態は空)とパターンスペースを入れ替える。
二つ目で評価を即座に終了します。
つまり、一行目の shebang のみがパターンスペースに残ります。

適当に改行を入れると少しわかりやすくなります。

```
for f in your_dir/*
do  s=`sed '-e /^#!\\/bin\\/sh$/!x' -eq "$f"` && \
    if [ "$s" ]
    then chmod +x "$f"
    fi
done
```